# How do I use the windows command prompt to copy a file

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

Hi there i would like to know how to copy a file that is in, lets say /rootfolder/subfolder
to the rootfolder

Comment: `copy /?` will tell you how to use `copy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the Command Prompt with administrative privilidges (they are needed for writing the file to C:\ ). I assume by "/rootfolder" you mean the top directory as opposed to a folder called "rootfolder" in the top directory.

Type in the command prompt `C:\subfolder\example.txt C:\`

For more information about using Copy type `copy /?`

Comment: Yes. Do i have to use C:\ ? can't I just use the two folders?

Comment: @Marcus Yes you can leave off the C drive part. I just put it there in case you mean the rootfolder of a drive other than C.